# How many RDD in the resulting DStream of reduceByKeyAndWindow

Tags: window, reduce, spark-streaming, rdd, dstream

I am currently working on a small spark job to compute stock correlation matrix from a DStream.

From a DStream[(time, quote)], I need to aggregate quotes (double) by time (Long) among multiple rdds, before computing correlations (considering all quotes of the rdds)

```
dstream.reduceByKeyAndWindow{./*aggregate quotes in Vectors*/..} 
       .forEachRDD {rdd => Statistics.corr(RDD[Vector])}
```

To my mind, this could be a solution if the resulting dstream (from reduceByKeyAndWindow) contains only 1 rdd with all aggregated quotes.

But I am not sure. How is the data distributed after reduceByKeyAndWindow? Is there a way to merge rdds in a dstream?

Comment: Please, Help.. (Leeloo, 1997)